# Is there a way orderer scheduling in HyperLedger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I set up the fabric network with 2 orderer nodes with kafka and 3 peer nodes. And I tested what will happen if an orderer shutdown suddenly. I expected the peers will connect to other alive orderer node to invoke chaincode. But the peers still request invoke to the dead orderer node.

Is there any settings to scheduling orderers?

Comment: Can you post the invoke request?

Comment: if orderer1 crash you can start sending invoke request to orderer2 by chainging its hostname

Comment: Orderers will either be 3, 5, or 7. It has to be an odd number to avoid split-brain scenarios, and larger than 1 in order to avoid single point of failures. Anything beyond 7 orderer nodes is considered overkill.